Can't access object in nested loop (JS and three.js)
I have a question about JavaScript and Threejs.
I made an object title_and_coord that stores sentences and their Vector3 coordinates (for wherever each sentence appears in my scene). I am trying to access this outside of my init() function in iterateObject(). But on debugging, I saw that the line for (let key in title_and_coord) { in iterateObject doesn’t run and skips to line word_and_coord[word] = shared_coords; 
If I run console.log(title_and_coord); globally, I indeed get an object in my console with the titles and their respective Vector3 values. Where am I going wrong? This is my first time with three.js so I apologise for the messy code! Thank you :)
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls';
import { FontLoader } from 'FontLoader';
import Stats from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.161.0/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js';
import * as GeometryUtils from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.161.0/examples/jsm/utils/GeometryUtils.js';

const sentences = [
"AI: Its nature and future", "Nature and scope of AI techniques", "Advancing mathematics by guiding human intuition with AI", "Cooperative AI: machines must learn to find common ground", "Inhibition of early atherogenesis in transgenic mice by human apolipoprotein AI", ......"Cross species quorum quenching using a native AI-2 processing enzyme", "Forecasting artificial intelligence on online customer assistance: Evidence from chatbot patents analysis", "A comprehensive survey of ai-generated content (aigc): A history of generative ai from gan to chatgpt"
];

//dict
const uniq_words = {
    "ai": 218,
    "its": 11,
    "nature": 16,
    "and": 247,
    "future": 12,
    "scope": 2,
......
    "interpretation": 2,
    "translational": 2,
    "making": 2,
    "ultrafiltration": 2
};

const word_and_coord = {};

//3 basic needs to display aanything in three js
let camera, scene, renderer;

//stores each title 
let message;

const title_and_coord = {};

init();
render();

function init() {

    //adding a camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 1500);

    //adding a scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

    //creating a font and using it as the geometry
    const loader = new FontLoader();
    loader.load('./fonts/Montserrat_Regular.json', function (font) {

        const color = 0x000000;
        const matLite = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: color,
            opacity: 1.0,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < sentences.length - 400; i++) {
            
            var title_coord = new THREE.Vector3();
            message = sentences[i];

            const shapes = font.generateShapes(message, 100);
            const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shapes);

            //generate a 1 or -1
            var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
            var plusOrMinus2 = Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1;
            
            var title = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, matLite);
                title.position.x = i*100*plusOrMinus*Math.random();

                title.position.y = plusOrMinus2 * (300 + ((Math.random()*100) + 0) + (Math.random()*1000));

                title.position.z = i*100;
                //plusOrMinus * ( 900 + ((Math.random()*10) + 0) + (Math.random()*100) + (Math.random()*1000) );

                //title.position.z = plusOrMinus2 * (900 + ((Math.random()*10) + 0) + (Math.random()*100) + (Math.random()*1000));

                //title.position.y = plusOrMinus2 * ( 900 + ((Math.random()*10) + 0) + (Math.random()*100) + (Math.random()*1000) );

                //title.rotateY(Math.random() * 1.1 * 3.14 * plusOrMinus2);
                title.scale.setScalar(0.9)
                
                scene.add(title);
                title_and_coord[message] = title.getWorldPosition(title_coord);

                //printing each title's coord
                
                //console.log(title.getWorldPosition(title_coord));
                //scene.add( line );

        //title loop finishes here
        }

        

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true} );
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    controls.update();
    controls.addEventListener('change', render);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

} // end init

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    render();
}

//render the entire scene
function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function iterateObject() {
 
    for (let word in uniq_words) {
        var shared_coords = [];
        
        //THIS LINE BELOW WORKS!! TITLEANDCOORD EXISTS INSIDE THIS SCOPE!
        //console.log(title_and_coord);

        for (const key in title_and_coord) {
            
            const lwrcase = key.toLowerCase();
            if (lwrcase.includes[word]){

                //append the coord of title to list/array initialized before the loop
                shared_coords.push(title_and_coord[key]);
                
            }
            
        }

        word_and_coord[word] = shared_coords;
        
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(word_and_coord));
}
iterateObject();

I ran console.log(title_and_coord) within iterateObject right after var shared_coords = [];. Then ran it another time, globally, both before and after iterateObject() is defined. It is not empty this is what I get both times:
console output

What happens if you console.log(key) in your for-in loop?

You're filling in title_and_coord in an asynchronous function. You're calling iterateObject() before the function has run.

Your problem is that the variable isn't populated yet when that code runs.
